# How can i return a database that gets a JSON POST Request in Flask?

Tags: python, json, database, flask

I know that my code is not good, i took parts of codes and try to work them together, but i get this error:

```
temp = data['temp']
```

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

I want to send a POST Request and that to go in my database and then to return that database to show on the web. pls help

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, json
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
 
def theform():
    return '''<form method="POST" action="/process">
                <input type="text" name="temp"
              </form>'''

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']=f'sqlite:///site.db'
db=SQLAlchemy(app)
db.init_app(app)

class JsonModel(object):
    def as_dict(self):
       return {c.name: getattr(self, c.name) for c in self.__table__.columns}

class User(db.Model, JsonModel):
    User_ID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(20))
    
    def __repr__(self):
       return f"User({'self.firstname'})"

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def index():
    data=request.get_json()

    temp = data['temp']
    firstname = temp
    return jsonify([u.as_dict() for u in User.query.all()])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: For the start, you can check the request.method to be POST before getting the rquest body as json, since GET won't have body. Secondly, body might be empty in POST and you are not validating it.

Comment: The issue is not related to your database. It's caused by how you access the request body as json.

Comment: why would your request have a json body if it's a GET request?